# Combining OpenXR and OVR Integration Plugins for Oculus Quest: Enabling Passthrough and XR Interaction Toolkit Integration, Unity Crash Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest, openxr

Combining OpenXR and OVR integration plugins for Oculus Quest: Is it possible to merge these plugins to utilize passthrough capabilities while also leveraging the XR Interaction Toolkit? If not, how can I interact with OVR hand controls using the XR Interaction Toolkit, or is it exclusive to the OpenXR plugin? Additionally, my attempt to integrate the OpenXR plugin and enable passthrough resulted in a Unity crash. Can someone provide guidance on achieving these goals successfully?

I configured hand tracking using the OpenXR plugin and added the Oculus integration asset to the scene. To enable passthrough capabilities, I placed the OVRCameraRig in the scene and utilized the passthrough script, making necessary adjustments to the settings.

My expectation was to successfully combine the features provided by the OpenXR plugin, such as hand tracking and the XR Interaction Toolkit, with the passthrough capabilities offered by the Oculus integration plugin. However, upon testing the implementation in Unity, it resulted in a crash.

I am seeking assistance to understand what went wrong with my approach and how to achieve the desired integration of passthrough capabilities and XR Interaction Toolkit while avoiding the Unity crash.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity crash sounds like a Unity bug, so best to follow up with them for that.

I would not expect it to work using both OpenXR and the pre-OpenXR plugin, though I know Oculus has put out a plugin that builds on the Unity OpenXR support to add additional vendor specific features.